# SVG animation animates backwards in safari

Tags: google-chrome, animation, firefox, svg, safari

I created a path in illustrator and then used some CSS in order to animate it. The svg animation works just fine in Chrome and Firefox, However, for a strange reason in safari it's animated backwards! The site is http://www.rw.limdez.eu and is located on the very top banner of the website. You can see it as soon as you click the link! You can only see this on desktop since for mobile it redirects you to the mobile version of the page! This is the CSS I used:

```
.smallline
{
stroke-dasharray:692;
stroke-dashoffset:-692;
animation-delay: 1s!important;
animation: draw-smallline 8s 1 forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes draw-smallline
{
0%{
stroke-dashoffset: -692;
}
100%
{
stroke-dashoffset:0;
}
}
```

Note1: I also tried it without `@-webkit-` but i have the exact same results!

Note2: I have seen other very similar questions to mine in stack-overflow but none of them were answered. Not in a way that solves my problem at least! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Negative works fine in Safari.

Instead of:

`stroke-dasharray:692;`

You should use:

`stroke-dasharray:692 692;`

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by changing the 0% dashoffset from -692 to 692! If i am not mistaken this occurred because safari does not deal efficiently with negative values!